# Visual Studio is giving an error when expanding a "Parameter Pack" even though the code is compiling fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class...T> void func(T...a) {};
template<class...U> void func1(U...b) {
    func(b...);
}


int main() {
    func1(1, 2, 6, 4, 64, 64, 4, 4, 5, 65, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to expand the parameter pack at line 5 using '...', Visual Studio 2022 is throwing the following error:

[image]

The code compiled perfectly but the error is shown while editing the code.

I also tried to compile it using "gcc" an it worked fine.

Comment: just restart VS or try "func<U...>(b...);"

Comment: Looks like you have Intellisense configured differently than compiler.

Comment: At least C++11 is required to compile this. You might have set IntelliSense to some earlier C++ version.

Comment: This code worked for me on Visual Studio 2022 with no changes at all. I just created a Console Application from the project wizard and pasted in the `int main()` code: [https://ibb.co/5K8fMgk](https://ibb.co/5K8fMgk)

Comment: From your screenshot, it's missing parentheses. And we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: You need to move your cursor to the template. Then an option will come up which says "Provide sample template arguments for IntelliSense". Click on it. Now provide a datatype as an argument(for example "int"). After that it should show the error.

Comment: Hi,   May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?  If it is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark  accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your detailed information.

The problem has been raised before and the Template Bar of the "Template
IntelliSense" feature does not currently support variadic templates.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Template-Intellisense-gives-error-with-v/484182?q=template+intellisense